# how to sync selectlist value with mysql table values

Tags: php, mysql, database, forms

When i enter the lenght and width  selected items sqft is correct but when it comes to the pricing, it always multiplies total sqft with the first items price... the price is within the while but it is not in a snyc with the products... any ideas where i should be looking in this?

```
while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) 
 { 
$resim = $info[resim];
$isim = $info[isim];
$boyut = $info[boyut];
$pcs = $info[adet];
$sqft = $info[sqft];
$TileNameList .= "<option value=\"$sqft\">$isim $boyut</option>";
$price .= $info[price];
}
/////////Formdan gelen yada Giden//////////////
$length =htmlspecialchars(stripslashes($_POST['Length'])); 
$width =htmlspecialchars(stripslashes($_POST['Width'])); 
$TileSqft =htmlspecialchars(stripslashes($_POST['TileName'])); 

/////Matematiksel islemler/////////

$equals = $length * $width;
$box = round($equals / $TileSqft);
$TotalSqft = $box * $TileSqft;
$TotalPrice = $TotalSqft * $price;
```

and this where i the form to get the length * width but total prices comes out wrong..

```
  <td><form id="form5" name="form5" method="post" action="">
        <select name="TileName" id="TileName">
        <option>Select</option>
<?php  echo ($TileNameList); ?>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td><input name="Length" type="text" id="Length"/></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="Width" id="Width"/></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="Sqft" id="Sqft" value="<?php echo ($equals); ?>"/></td>
      <td><?php echo "You will need <span style=\"color:red\">$box</span> Boxes<br> Which is <span style=\"color:red\">$TotalSqft</span> "; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo "$$TotalPrice"; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr >
      <td colspan="6" align="center">
        <input type="submit" name="Submit" id="Submit" value="Submit" />
      </form></td>
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Comment: what is this $price .= $info[price]; why are you using this concatenation?

Comment: Try changing `$price .= $info[price];` to `$price += $info['price'];` and be sure to initialize variable BEFORE while. `$price = 0;`

Comment: this change doesnt work Giovanne for example when i put length times width(10x10) 100 sqft.. the product that i choose price should come out 129 but instead it shows 891 i dont even know how it gets this number... because in the price list there is no such pricing as $8.91  to give that result

Answer (score 0):

You are appending the `$price` I think you shoul add the `price` 
Code is

```
$price=0;//Add this line
while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) 
{ 
$resim = $info[resim];
$isim = $info[isim];
$boyut = $info[boyut];
$pcs = $info[adet];
$sqft = $info[sqft];
$TileNameList .= "<option value=\"$sqft\">$isim $boyut</option>";
$price += $info[price];//change this line
}
/////////Formdan gelen yada Giden//////////////
$length =htmlspecialchars(stripslashes($_POST['Length'])); 
$width =htmlspecialchars(stripslashes($_POST['Width'])); 
$TileSqft =htmlspecialchars(stripslashes($_POST['TileName'])); 

/////Matematiksel islemler/////////

$equals = $length * $width;
$box = round($equals / $TileSqft);
$TotalSqft = $box * $TileSqft;
$TotalPrice = $TotalSqft * $price;
```

Comment: this change doesnt work Rohan for example when i put length times width(10x10) 100 sqft.. the product that i choose price should come out 129 but instead it shows 891 i dont even know how it gets this number... because in the price list there is no such pricing as $8.91  to give that result

Comment: First you check what value you get in `$price`, here it is the sum of all values found in your `$data` do you want it should be the sum of all `price values` found in `$data`

Comment: Test by using yhese lines:
`echo $price;echo $length =htmlspecialchars(stripslashes($_POST['Length'])); echo $width =htmlspecialchars(stripslashes($_POST['Width'])); echo $TileSqft =htmlspecialchars(stripslashes($_POST['TileName']));
echo $equals = $length * $width;echo $box = ound($equals / $TileSqft);echo $TotalSqft = $box * $TileSqft;echo $TotalPrice = $TotalSqft * $price;`

Comment: Rohan $price is unit price so i dont need the sum for all... I just need it, so it multiplies by the $TotalSqft the result i need. also when i  echo $price i get 8.91 and when i echo inside while i get this..02.954.245.537.227.227.227.227.227.227.227.227.227.227.227.227.227.227.227.227.227.227.227.227.227.227.227.227.227.227.227.227.227.227.227.227.227.227.227.227.227.227.227.227.227.227.227.227.227.227.227.227.227.227.227.227.227.227.227.227.227.227.227.227.227.227.227.227.227.228.91

Comment: These values are very unclear to anyone, you should specify the field which contains every value.
If you want a single `price` then which price you want from `while loop` or you simply you can use `$price = $info[price];` in place of addition of all values.

Comment: this is what i am actually trying to do... Lets say there is 10 products  each has Name Quantity in box and price...so in this calculator i tell the system the dimensions are x amount. automatically that x amount divides with quantity to find out how many boxes needed. also automatically multiplies the box quantity with the price... the above coding i get the quantities but it simply does not finds its price to multiply its either multiply by the first product or the last product..

Comment: Can you give me your dummy data with what you needed(can say formula to find), so I can understand it more.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24163/discussion-between-rohan-kumar-and-coderwannabe)